# Convert chart blade view to pdf in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, charts, laravel-8, canvasjs

I want to convert the bellow blade view to pdf document.

The blade view contains Canvasjs chart. The headers and paragraphs when i export the blade view show normally. But only the chart doesn't show.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script>
 window.onload = function() {
  
 var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
   animationEnabled: true,
   theme: "light2",
   title:{
     text: "Gold Reserves"
   },
   axisY: {
     title: "Gold Reserves (in tonnes)"
   },
   data: [{
     type: "column",
     yValueFormatString: "#,##0.## tonnes",
     dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
   }]
 });
 chart.render();
  
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
 <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>



public function build()
    {
        $pdf = FacadesPdf::loadView('Mails.myTestMail',["details"=>$this->details]);
        return $this->subject('Mail from UVARA ROI CALCULATOR.')
        ->attachData($pdf->output(),'report.pdf')
        ->view('Mails.myTestMail');
    }
```

I am converting this on the Backend level, i know that i can make it using javascript, but i want to generate the view dynamically and export as pdf and send it by email.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i faced this problem before , i think you cant do this in backend level , after many days , i did it with javascript because it contain charts that loaded after page render

Comment: @MohamedAhmed do you think that if we create our own chart design using html and css it will be generated as pdf?

Comment: if , it you use html and css only you can but js is hard

Comment: Thank you @MohamedAhmed